# how to select all values of elements with a .innnerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Button – calls a function that displays all of the innerHTML values of all
HTML elements on the page.

what would I use to acquire all the innerHTML values and display them. I have tried searching for various things but haven't found info or examples that deals with innerHTML specifically.

edit: this is for a homework objective.

Comment: Can you describe what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `console.log(document.querySelector("html").innerHTML)`...

Comment: @Marty edited, but my first setence describes what I am trying to achieve, a function that will aloow me to display all innerHTML property values of all HTML elements..... so any element that has an innerHTML property value i need to collect it and display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you'd do this... an example using jQuery:

```
 $('*').each(function() { console.log( $(this).html() ); });
```

or...

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
    console.log( tags[i].innerHTML );
}
```

Comment: There would be an enormous amount of repetition since most elements are children of some other element.

Comment: @ClaytonSmith what does the "*" (asterisk)

Comment: @RobG the page in which this occurs is very basic, a few divs, headers, and paragraphs. while it may be excessive. My first sentence in my post are the instructions given to me. So I have to accomplish this somehow. Would you suggest something else?

Comment: @kronis72 an asterisk is a glob operator (think of it as a wildcard representing all elements), and means it will select all elements.

Comment: @kronis72—per the comment by Derek 朕會功夫. The innerHTML of the HTML element contains the innerHTML of every element in the page.

Comment: @ClaytonSmith—also much more efficient to replace `$(this).html()` with `this.innerHTML`.